# powershell cmdlet C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm tired to search about way to use powershell in C#, this first time to use Powershell and I don't know how to add it in C#, i have my codes working in Powershell any help to add in C#?

```
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts"
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList"
New-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList" -name BigBear -value "0" -propertyType DWord
```

(BigBear) it's name and I want to change it with textbox

i tried this

```
    private void Shell()
    {
        using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            //    using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            //    {
            //        powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
            //        powerShell.AddScript(@"Hidden.ps1");
            //        //powerShell.AddParameter("UserName", UserName.Text);
            //        powerShell.Invoke();
            //    }

            using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShell.Runspace = runspace;

            powerShell.AddCommand("New-Item -Path \"HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\"");
            powerShell.AddCommand("New-Item -Path \"HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\\UserList\"");
            powerShell.AddCommand("New-ItemProperty -path \"HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\\UserList\" -name " + UserName.Text + " -value \"0\" -propertyType DWord");

            //powerShell.AddParameter("ParamA", varA);

            var results = powerShell.Invoke();

            // Do whatever with results
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Here are some links that describes how it can be done. But your question is not very detailed on your requirements... The last one have code you can download and try/modify!

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

Comment: i tried this two before but always get error when i change Command or script or Parameter